# Set visibility by subtype in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, table-of-contents, subtype

I am wondering if it is possible in ArcMap to isolate a particular subtype within a feature class to be visible in the map.  I have a feature class with several subtypes based on an attribute field.  I would like to make it so that I can turn these subtypes on or off with a checkbox in the TOC the way that you can with layers or groups.

This would essentially be the next level down in the tree: 
Layers->Groups->Feature Classes->Subtypes

Comment: Duplicate the layers and set Definition Query for each sub-type

Comment: I have added some screenshots as an answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Duplicate your layers to the number of sub-types

[image]

In each of the duplicated layers, set a Definition Query to limit that layer to only display one of the sub-type values

[image]

And you can now turn on/off sub-types as desired

[image]

Comment: That gif alone deserves an upvote

Answer (score 3):

If you happen to have access to Esri's Production Mapping Extension (what used to be called PLTS), they have a Add Subtypes button that will do exactly this.  Here is the help page for this particular tool:

[Adding subtypes as layers](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/extensions/production-mapping/adding-subtypes-as-layers.htm)